# Frame Animations only start one time

Tags: android, animationdrawable

I have created a frame animations by the code below. I want every time I click at the button the animation will start but it **only work** at first time.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/frame"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Start Animation"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

frame.xml

```
<animation-list
    android:oneshot="true"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_heart_0" android:duration="300" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_heart_50" android:duration="300" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_heart_75" android:duration="300" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_heart_100" android:duration="300" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_heart_0" android:duration="300" />
</animation-list>
```

Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startAnimation();
            }
        });
    }

    public void startAnimation(){
         ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        ((AnimationDrawable) img.getBackground()).start();
    }
}
```

How can I make the animation can start whenever I click at the Button?
Any help or suggestion would be great appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution that I found. I try to stop animation if it is running before I start it again. I think animation not stop even it have gone through all frame

```
if(((AnimationDrawable) imageView.getBackground()).isRunning()){
      ((AnimationDrawable) imageView.getBackground()).stop();
}
((AnimationDrawable) imageView.getBackground()).start();
```

Answer (score 2):

You try `stop()` animation after 300 duration in `MainActivity`. I think it not recognize either you stop or not maybe. It stop after 300 , right ? but i think maybe app recognize it still start.

Comment: thank you I do think stop animation manually can make animation can start again

Answer (score 0):

In order to run "one shot animation" again:

```
private void runAnimation(ImageView imageView) {
    AnimationDrawable animation = (AnimationDrawable) imageView.getBackground();
    animation.setVisible(true, true);
    animation.start();
}
```